How to pass a double value of an editText to another activity in android?
I'm working on an activity in android studio in which I need to compute area and perimeter. I used intent and view Binding to access and pass the value of the user input in the edit Text to another activity that would do the computations. However, I received an error in the second activity stating "No value passed for parameter 'defaultValue'". Is there a better way to pass a numerical double value to another activity? I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.
MainActivity.kt:
val length = binding.edtTextLength.text
val width = binding.editTextWidth.text

intent.putExtra("Length", length)
intent.putExtra("Width", width)

MActivity2.kt:
val getHeight = intent.getDoubleExtra("Length")
val getWeight = intent.getDoubleExtra("Width")


You should do it like this
val length = binding.edtTextLength.text.toString()
val width = binding.editTextWidth.text.toString()
and in second activity
val lengthValue = length.toDouble()
val widthValue = width.toDouble()

@Akshay then how would I get the value of the variables if I don't use the intent.getDoubleExtra?

You need to get the values of the string, instead of using getDoubleExtra use getStringExtra

@Akshay when I did that, another error occured. It says, "Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?".

Make it non-null use !! and while assigning the value you can do --> actualValue ?: "0.0". By this you will always have non null values.

Let me know if that works/helps, you can upvote the comments.

@Akshay I don't know what is happening but now it only displays "NaN". It doesn't compute the input the user type in.

@EJLin - Convert the text value to double and send please ..
val length = binding.edtTextLength.text.toString().toDouble()
val width = binding.editTextWidth.text.toString().toDouble()

@EJLin does the code work for you? or are you still stuck?
